Building TCP proxy
I'm a newbie and study Black Hat Python. I write code with Python 3 and have problems when executing my code.
Depend on code in Black Hat Python,
I write BuildTCPProxy.py
def receive_from(connection):
    buffer = ""
    #we set a 2 second timeout; depending on your target
    #this may need to be adjusted
    connection.settimeout(2)
    
    try:
        #keep reading into buffer until
        #there's no more data
        
        #or we time put
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(4096)
            
            if not data:
                break
            
            buffer += data
        
    except:
        #This is code I write more to show the error, may be...
        print(f'Error........ When connect {connection}')
        pass
    
    return buffer

def request_handler(buffer):
    #peform packet modifications
    return buffer

def respone_handler(buffer):
    #peform packet modifications
    return buffer

    

The problem happen here when I run my code, I'm stuck on this and don't know the reason
def proxy_handle(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    
    #connect to remote host
    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
    
    #receive data from the remote end if necessary
    if receive_first:
        
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        hexdump(remote_buffer)
        
        #send it to our respone handler
        remote_buffer = respone_handler(remote_buffer)
        
        #if we have data to send to our local client, send it
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print(f'[~] Sending {len(remote_buffer)} bytes to localhost.')
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)
            
        #now lets loop and read from local
            #send to remote, send to local
        #rinse, wash, repeat
        
    while True:
            
        #read from local host
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)
            
        if len(local_buffer):
            print(f'[~] Received {len(local_buffer)} bytes from localhost.')
            hexdump(local_buffer)
                
        #send it to our request handler
        local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer).encode()
            
        #send off the data to the remote host
        remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
        print(f'Send to remote:\n\r{local_buffer.decode()}')
            
        #receive back the respone 
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
            
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print(f'[~] Received {len(remote_buffer)} bytes from remote.')
            hexdump(remote_buffer)
                
            #send to our respone handler 
            remote_buffer = respone_handler(remote_buffer).encode()
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)
            print(f'Send to localhost:\n\r{remote_buffer.decode()}')
                
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print(f'[*] No more data. Closing connections.')
            break            


def sever_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    
    sever = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    try:
        sever.bind((local_host, local_port))
    except:
        print(f'[!!] Failed to listen on {local_host}:{local_port}')
        print(f'[!!] Check for other listening sockets or correct permissions.')
        sys.exit(-1)
    
    print(f'[*] Listening on {local_host}:{local_port}')
    
    sever.listen(5)
    
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = sever.accept()
        print(f'[~] Receiving connection from client {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}')
        proxy_thread = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handle, args=(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first))
        proxy_thread.start()

def main():
    
    if(len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5):
        print("Usage: ./BuildTCPProxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] [remoteport] [receive_first]")
        print("Example: ./BuildTCPProxy.py 127.0.0.1 9999 10.12.132.1 9000 True")
        sys.exit(0)
    
    #set up local listening parameters    
    local_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])
    
    #set up remote target
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])
    
    #this tells our proxy to connect and receive data
    receive_first = sys.argv[5]
    
    if "True" in receive_first:
        receive_first = True
    else:
        receive_first = False
    
    #now spin up our listening socket
    sever_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

democonnect.py
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_post = 21

#create a socket to connect
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_post))

message = "Test test"
print(message)

#send some data 
client.send(message.encode())

#receive some data
respone = client.recv(4096)
client.close()
print(respone)

When I run my code, I get the result
democonnect.py
Test test 
b''

BuildTCPProxy.py
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:21
[~] Receiving connection from client 127.0.0.1:55252
Error........ When connect <socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.19.189.11', 38505), raddr=('3.20.32.97', 21)>
Error........ When connect <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 21), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 55252)>
Send to remote:

Error........ When connect <socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.19.189.11', 38505), raddr=('3.20.32.97', 21)>
[*] No more data. Closing connections.


A proxy shouldn't alternate between remote->local and local->remote, since the application may not be a simple operation like that. You should either use independent threads for each direction, or use select.select() to wait for something on both sockets at once.
